# Integromat send images directly from text without translation

Tags: make.com

i've a bot into integromat that works fine when i send a text to translate using the google translate API, but when an image is send to it it crashes due to the image because obviously it can not be translated.
So, my question is if there can be images avoid to be translated using some integromat module to extract only text from a message and send the image also without tranlating it.
This is my actual bot integrated with telegram for text only.

Thanks for any help
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If image files are causing an error in the "send message" module, you can set an error handler and use another "send message" module as the error handler. Here's a guide on how to use error handlers: https://support.integromat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001986413-Introduction-to-Error-Handling